# Exporting Data to Salesforce.com

Tags: marketing-cloud

We're using a Master DE to store main contact data, we're updating this MasterDE from different other DE's(via SQL's) and from external triggered sends.

What are some common ways to sync that data back to the Salesforce Record? Currently we update Salesforce after updating the MasterDE. That makes it hard to maintain new fields etc. Is there a way to update from a scheduled activity to Salesforce?

Comment: Sending stuff back back to SFDC is painful

Comment: You can use AmScript and SSJS to the make a post call to the SF Object

Comment: But beware of governor limits re API calls

Comment: @Data_Kid sure, but to use Ampscript/SSJS, I either need a landingpage visit or an email that will be sent. Neither ways are an option. Isn't there a mechanism that can rin in the background?

Comment: You can run SSJS as an script activity in automation studio

Comment: But you are right before they introduced this you had to have a landing page